# Flask not served in Anaconda/Docker Container

Tags: python, azure, docker, flask, anaconda

Hello (I am going crazy here)
I am trying to create docker container with a flask web app + miniconda environment which is then deployed to a container for web apps in azure

With docker build 
docker build -t ana .
the container is successfully created but running it with 
docker run ana

leads to nothing happening (no error, just running but the flask server is not started)

the application itself is called as print statements are actually displayed

I tried the with PIP before as outlined here:
https://www.martinnorin.se/exposing-python-machine-learning-models-using-flask-docker-and-azure/

and it works but I cannot make it work with anaconda......

my environment.yml

```
name: ana
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - certifi=2018.11.29=py36_0
  - click=7.0=py36_0
  - flask=1.0.2=py36_1
  - intel-openmp=2019.1=144
  - itsdangerous=1.1.0=py36_0
  - jinja2=2.10=py36_0
  - pip=19.0.1=py36_0
  - pycparser=2.19=py36_0
  - python-dateutil=2.7.5=py36_0
  - pytz=2018.9=py36_0
  - setuptools=40.7.3=py36_0
  - six=1.12.0=py36_0
  - werkzeug=0.14.1=py36_0
  - wheel=0.32.3=py36_0
  - waitress=1.2.0=py36_0
prefix: C:\Users\jji309\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\ana
```

my dockerfile

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

# Set the ENTRYPOINT to use bash
# (this is also where you’d set SHELL,
# if your version of docker supports this)
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "-c" ]

# Conda supports delegating to pip to install dependencies
# that aren’t available in anaconda or need to be compiled
# for other reasons. In our case, we need psycopg compiled
# with SSL support. These commands install prereqs necessary
# to build psycopg.
#RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
# libpq-dev \
# build-essential \
#&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Use the environment.yml to create the conda environment.
 ADD environment.yml /tmp/environment.yml
 WORKDIR /tmp
RUN [ "conda", "env", "create" ]

ADD . /code

# Use bash to source our new environment for setting up
# private dependencies—note that /bin/bash is called in
# exec mode directly
ADD setup.py /code/shared/setup.py
WORKDIR /code/shared
RUN [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "source activate ana && python setup.py develop" ]

ADD setup.py /code/setup.py
WORKDIR /code
RUN [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "source activate ana && python setup.py develop" ]

# We set ENTRYPOINT, so while we still use exec mode, we don’t
# explicitly call /bin/bash
ADD app.py /code/app.py
EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "source activate ana && exec python /code/app.py" ]
```

my app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from waitress import serve
from flask import request
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

@app.route("/do_post", methods=['POST'])
def post_method():
    json = request.get_json()
    name = json["name"]
    age = json["age"]
    return "Hello {}. You're {} years old.".format(name, age)   

# This is important so that the server will run when the docker container has been started. 
# Host=0.0.0.0 needs to be provided to make the server publicly available.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    serve(app,host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```